# Is there a concurrency limitation in async/queue js library?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a async/queue function (https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue) and i'm wonder is there a limit on concurrency parameter?

Comment: Per the documentation on that page you provided:  *"concurrency number <optional> Infinity 
An optional integer for determining the maximum number of tasks that can be run in parallel. By default, as many as possible."*  --  So infinite number of concurrency -- Though I suppose it would depend on the size of your application and the power of the browser.

Comment: Do a find on the page .. Search for "concurrency"  About half way down on the page

Comment: As a general rule, modern software libraries rarely have arbitrary limits. In the rare exceptions, the limits will be enormous. The only limits you're ever likely to encounter are memory. Also, if you process large amounts, it may be slow.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a [`QueueObject`](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#QueueObject), which - according to the documentation - has no limit specified:

> Concurrency: an integer for determining how many worker functions should be run in parallel. This property can be changed after a queue is created to alter the concurrency on-the-fly.

Also on the documentation, [`AsyncFunction`](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/global.html)s have no limit on concurrency:

> An optional integer for determining the maximum number of tasks that can be run in parallel. By default, as many as possible.